# Deleting trailing whitespaces after recursion methods

Tags: java, recursion, nodes

I'm running through a binary tree to print print a string element in a certain order, it's actually asking for a return value of a string, I'm just having issues getting rid of the trailing whitespaces, .trim() will not work as it uses recursion and so on a test case that uses 7 nodes it will have a couple where it delete's the necessary whitespace, the best solution I could come up with is an if statement to delete the last index of space but that has the same issues. This is more a recursion logic related issue than anything else.

The correct answer: "a b d e c f g"

The answer my code gets: "a b d ec fg"

```
public static String travel(TreeNode<String> root) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
        if(root != null) {
            sb.append(root.getData() + " ");
            sb.append(travel(root.getLeft()));
            sb.append(travel(root.getRight()));
        }
        
        if(sb.length() > 2) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(" "));
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
public static String travel(TreeNode<String> root) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if(root != null) {
        sb.append(root.getData());
        String left = travel(root.getLeft());
        String right = travel(root.getRight());
        if (left.length() > 0)
            sb.append(" " + left);
        if (right.length() > 0)
            sb.append(" " + right);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: In the case when the root node only has a left child, this method adds unnecessary space in the end. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Above comment is right there's an additional space with the test case of only a left child so it would be "a  b" instead of "a b"

Comment: @anonuser678 is it working now as you expected (i edited the answer)?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
public static String travel(TreeNode<String> root) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if(root != null) {
        sb.append(root.getData());
        sb.append(" " + travel(root.getLeft()));
        sb.append(" " + travel(root.getRight()));
    }
    
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: has the same issue as the first answer but now it's on the right side

Comment: Note the `trim` in the end. So, if unnecessary space is added, it is going to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're writing a [preorder binary tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order,_NLR).

Baking stringification into the algorithm overburdens the function, making it less generally useful. I recommend returning a list, then the caller is free to join it into a string any way they wish. If this is part of an algorithm challenge and your method header is fixed, write a helper method to do the recursion and let the boilerplate method stringify the returned array.

Another way to make your code more generic is to return the list of nodes rather than their data. Again, this gives the caller flexibility to do what they want with the result.

"Traverse" is a more typical name than "travel", by the way.

I'll leave it as a String, but it's better to write this method as accepting nodes of type T, and make the result `ArrayList<TreeNode>`.

```java
public static String preorderToString(TreeNode<String> root) {
    var result = new ArrayList<String>();
    traversePreorder(root, result);
    return String.join(" ", result);
}

public static void traversePreorder(
    TreeNode<String> root,
    ArrayList<String> result
) {
    if (root != null) {
        result.add(root.getData());
        traversePreorder(root.getLeft());
        traversePreorder(root.getRight());
    }
}
```